# Vision API incorrect logo detection with high confidence

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I have notice a lot of false logo recognition result with high confidence score from Google Vision API. The logo in my input image is rotaed 90 degrees. I found Google Vision is having issue recognizing the correct Logo when it is not in the horizontal orientation. It always return 'Lenovo' as the logo for those kind of images with more than 80% confidence.

Is there a way for Google Vision API to fix this issue or how can I rotated the image before use it as the input?